# Error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context player= new Player(playerId,skill,level,points);

Tags: java

`player= new Player(playerId,skill,level,points);` is showing error= error:

> non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context player= new Player(playerId,skill,level,points);

How to resolve this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player[] player=new Player[4];
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=0;i<player.length;i++)
        {
            int playerId=sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            String skill=sc.nextLine();
            String level=sc.nextLine();
            int points=sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            player= new Player(playerId,skill,level,points);
            sc.close();
            }}
```

Comment: I think we need the definitions of both `player` and `Player` to resolve this.  For the later we need the whole class please.

Comment: One thing that is obvious is `player` is an array, so you need to assign it with an index variable: `player[i] = new Player...` but I don't see how that leads to the error message you gave us.

Comment: do you really want to be closing your scanner inside your loop? That means it will close after one iteration. It isn't related to your compile error, but it will be a logical error later

Comment: your error is in your Player constructor.

Comment: Why are you assigning `new Player(...)` to a `Player[] player` reference?